# vim keyword complete when omni complete returns nothing?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Im trying to use omni completions and if it returns nothing i want to use normal keyword completion?

i thougt %omnifunc != '' should do it... 
but what am i missing?
Here is my function.

```
function! CleverTab()
  if pumvisible()
    return "\<C-N>"
  endif
  if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
    return "\<Tab>"
  elseif &omnifunc != ''
    return "\<C-X>\<C-O>"
  else
    return "\<C-N>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=CleverTab()<CR>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let g:stop_autocomplete=0

function! CleverTab(type)
    if a:type=='omni'
        if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
            let g:stop_autocomplete=1
            return "\<TAB>"
        elseif !pumvisible() && !&omnifunc
            return "\<C-X>\<C-O>\<C-P>"
        endif
    elseif a:type=='keyword' && !pumvisible() && !g:stop_autocomplete
        return "\<C-X>\<C-N>\<C-P>"
    elseif a:type=='next'
        if g:stop_autocomplete
            let g:stop_autocomplete=0
        else
            return "\<C-N>"
        endif
    endif
    return ''
endfunction

inoremap <silent><TAB> <C-R>=CleverTab('omni')<CR><C-R>=CleverTab('keyword')<CR><C-R>=CleverTab('next')<CR>
```

Comment: oh damn, I forget it ;) anyway, you should double check pumvisible for each menu

Comment: hmm... not getting it to work, if i tab after a space i get a tab, then immediately i get a new autocomplete menu. i tried this as a first if statement:
    if strpart( getline('.'), 0, col('.')-1 ) =~ '^\s*$'
        return "\<Tab>"

Comment: I think there's a small bug -- I don't know vim scripting, but I think you need
  < && &omnifunc != "" >
after where you currently have
  < !&omnifunc >
for the case when I hit Tab in a non-omnifunc file and want to do keyword completion.